# Average execution time for T gate

Tags: experimental-realization, clifford-group

Using the Q# resource estimator, I found out that my program, meant to do graph coloring using Grover's algorithm, could be decomposed into ~500-1000*x T gates, where x in the number of iterations, often ranging between 5 and 10. This means I am considering thousands of T gates.

I am considering T gates because they can be a universal gate when paired with the Clifford group which is easy to simulate.

I am interested to know the average time it would take for a quantum computer (any type) to execute one of these T gates, time which I would then multiply to estimate the runtime of my program.

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Even though there is a T-count, this often isn't necessarily a good approximation of runtime cost - notably, if you have a multiply controlled NOT gate, Q# will incur T-costs, but your architecture may be able to apply the CCNOT natively

Comment: Is the question here more about just framing the time cost of your program? Because if so, it's safe to say the runtime will likely be within hours/minutes (rather than days/weeks)

Comment: @C.Kang I was more interested about the difference between a simulation and a real quantum computer in 10 node graph situation

Comment: Ah, in that case the quantum computer will run almost certainly much faster than your simulation. Gates typically take on the order of ms / ns to apply

Comment: @C.Kang what would a good runtime cost approximation be then ? I have to do this for a paper, since I tested graphs from size 1-8, I would like to generalize my results. I saw that there was a resource estimator built in, and I thought I was made for this kind thing. However, I have troubles evaluating what every character means (I am referring to the first comment)

Comment: I would refer you to Google's paper - while it depends a lot on architecture, they did a million samples in 200 sec, which shows how quickly these architectures can run https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1666-5. It's hard to know how long a real quantum device would take given the size of the problem

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give more specifics, I'm very much algorithm side. Maybe someone who's hardware side can give more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the surface code there are two major costs to T gates: the spacetime cost and the reaction time cost.

The spacetime cost is due to the need to perform magic state distillation of a T state for each T gate, which takes hundreds of operations. A T gate factory producing a T state every hundred microseconds can easily monopolize a hundred thousand qubits. This isn't technically a limitation on the time of the computation, because you can just add more and more factories until the T gates are coming at any rate you want, but it represents a large cost that forces hard tradeoffs between more space usage and longer runtime. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01238 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.06903. For scale:

[image]

The reaction time cost has to do with the fact that when you teleport through a T gate, you instead apply its inverse 50% of the time. You realize that it happened, but it still has to be fixed before the computation can properly progress. Ultimately this means that if you have a series of T gates to apply, you are limited by how fast you can figure out if you did T or inverse T and then correct it. In fact this is the only part of a quantum computation that isn't embarrassingly parallel. There is a technique where this time is minimized by preparing a wordline for each possible correction, and teleporting through the one that matters. With that technique the T depth of your circuit times your control system's reaction time is a lower bound on how fast the computation can finish. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.4626 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.08916.

[image]